# When is ubiquitous container deleted?

Tags: swift, containers, icloud, nsfilemanager

I'm playing with iCloud Drive Documents/ubiquitous containers to share documents between devices my app is installed on.

So far, everything seems to work fine. I can manage documents, get notified about changes if another device adds something, etc.

But I'm wondering: Since my container is private, it is not visible in the "Files" application on my iPhones/iPads or in the iCloud folder on my Mac. I can only see it when I go to ~/Library/Mobile Documents in Mac's terminal. But when will it actually be deleted? Once I uninstall the last instance of my app? Will it just be there forever without the user being able to free the occupied space?

Answer (score 1):

Your private app container will persist in iCloud even after you have deleted the app.

You have the ability to purge space used by the private container in the iCloud Preferences - Manage Storage panel. On iOS it allows you to purge the contents. On macOS, it helps you open the container with Finder (`~/Library/Mobile Documents/<app-container>/Documents`). You can then delete files from the container.

You will note however that the container directory will persist (and will reappear if you delete it).

Comment: Is there ANY method, API, interface or other technique to destroy these folders? It's insane that there is no way to manage them. What if there's sensitive data inside that you want removed?

Comment: You can remove the container directory and contents on macOS. The container directory will reappear - but not the old contents - so your sensitive data can be managed. I understand on iOS using iCloud/Manage Account Storage the same effect is achieved.